# How to apply transition effects between knockout amd components

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-components

Is it possible to have an animated transition between components in knockout which are loaded using require? So when state() changes, components are faded/slid into place?

I have done similar things in the past with fadeVisible, but this does not appear to work with amd/require and the new components api. Any ideas? Thanks :)

### Registration

```
// Register knockout components
ko.components.register('breadcrumb', { require: './Modules/Breadcrumb/Breadcrumb' });
ko.components.register('splash', { require: './Modules/Splash/Splash' });
ko.components.register('catalogue', { require: './Modules/Catalogue/Catalogue' });
ko.components.register('requests', { require: './Modules/Requests/Requests' });
```

### Usage

```
   <div id="main">

        <breadcrumb></breadcrumb>

        <!-- ko if: state() === 'home' -->
        <splash></splash>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: state() === 'catalogue' -->
        <catalogue></catalogue>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: state() === 'requests' -->
        <requests></requests>
        <!-- /ko -->

   </div>
```

Fiddle: [How to apply transition effects between knockout amd components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25767947/how-to-apply-transition-effects-between-knockout-amd-components)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Create a custom binding like in this example: http://knockoutjs.com/examples/animatedTransitions.html

Actually, the documentation states that any control binding attribute *must* be placed outside a component:

> Therefore if you want to use a control flow binding such as if or foreach, then you must wrap it around your custom element rather than using it directly on the custom element

However, custom bindings cannot be used in virtual elements so it is necessary to place a component inside a wrapping `div`

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-custom-elements.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have tried that and it does not appear to work e.g. <splash data-bind="fadeVisible: state() === 'home'></splash>

Comment: I updated your fiddle to v. 3. Check it out. Check also mine: http://jsfiddle.net/cdL7nxLk/3/

Comment: If you surround your component with an element it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ek5m61ot/1/

Comment: Appears like the latter works ok, thank you. Would that also lazy load ok with requirejs, as that is what i am using? Though I can't recreate that in the fiddle :(

Comment: I can confirm that losing the container less control flow statements (<!-- ko if: state() === 'home' --> etc), breaks the on demand loading in require, although it does transition ok :(

Comment: Looks like there is a compromise based on your input (thank you).

            <div data-bind="fadeVisible: state() === 'home'">
                <!-- ko if: state() === 'home' -->
                <splash></splash>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </div>

Comment: Why you guys downvote when it works and been accepted as a valid answer??